# How can I play a sound clip (.ogg file) at startup?

Tags: sound

I can play these clips on command with `aplay`, so I was wondering if there is a way to run that aplay command as soon as the login screen appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of places that you can think of, one of them  can be `/etc/profile` for all users and `~/.profile` for each user.

Another thing you can do is to add a startup command, open dash search for "startup" and add your command there:

[image]